Переход по ссылке, по достижению 0 сек JS
Сразу прошу прощение за не очень "умный" вопрос.
С js вообще случайно пересекся. Есть простенький таймер, и нужно что бы по достижению 0 сек что бы осуществлялся переход по ссылки.
Сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос.
Заранее благодарю за помощь!


let time = 3600;
const countDownE1 = document.getElementById("tiime")
var secs = 10;
var timer = setInterval(tick,1000)
function tick(){
    countDownE1.innerHTML = ('Осталось '+(--secs)+' секунд');
}
                        <p id="tiime"></p>




Решение
Вот так:


const countDownE1 = document.getElementById("tiime");
let secs = 10;
const index = setInterval(() => {
  countDownE1.textContent = `Осталось ${--secs} секунд`;
  if (secs > 0) return;
  clearInterval(index);
  location.href = `https://i.sstatic.net/ykA5rXg0.gif`;
}, 1000);
<p id="tiime"></p>



